# How to write the simplest Hudson/Jenkins plugin?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have an executable with unit tests (my custom framework) and I want to run it after each build using Hudson.

I would expect to register my exe as a Hudson step and make sure it produces the correct report format.

So far all tutorials I have found seem like overkilling with all the configuration files and interfaces. I'll go that path if I need - but what's the simplest way to achieve what I want? I'm looking for a good link with a "template" that I can adjust for my needs.

Comment: Why do you need to write a plugin to do this. You can achieve this with a post build step. Can you explain what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I finally did - a post build step that runs my tests and generates JUnit output format

Comment: I submitted this as answer I would appreciate the votes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that creating an app for this is overkill, you could probably do a post build step that runs and generates junit output format.

Goodluck.

Comment: We did it that way too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329215/how-to-get-ctest-results-in-hudson-jenkins