# Executing Google Test on Jenkins (Easy)

Tags: jenkins, build, googletest

I managed to install Google Test on Jenkins.

I use cmake to build the test executable and everything works fine.

The stupid question I have now is:

How do I automatically let Jenkins run google test?
Do I have to write a shell script for this or is there a better way?

---

I know that one could run it in ant but since I use cmake I doubt that this is the right way to go.

Comment: There is no "special" task for google test that I'm aware of. I'm just using the shell to run the executable. But there are plugins to publish the test results in junit format from the google test run.

Answer (score 5):

There's no builtin or pluggable "Googletest automation" for Jenkins.
You've built the test executable with CMake in a build step.
Execute the test executable in a subsequent build step
with [xml test reporting enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8268584/1362568)
and configure the build to [archive or otherwise publish the test reports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11540633/1362568).