# googletest - How can I combine my parameterized tests into one when outputting results?

Tags: c++, googletest

Say I have the following class and parameterized test:

```
class SimpleTest : public ::testing::Test, public ::testing::WithParamInterface<int> {};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(SimpleTests, SimpleTest, ::testing::Range(1, 10));

TEST_P(SimpleTest, TestGreaterThanZero) {
    int i = GetParam();
    ASSERT_GT(i, 0);
}
```

When I run googletest, I get 10 lines of output, one for each parameter in the range.

Now say I want to change my range from 10 to 10 million. If I ran that, I would get 10 million lines of output (which would be way too much). Is there a way I could group all the output for this parameterized test into one, and simply report the first error?

I know I could rewrite my test case to loop through the values and assert on each one, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this from googletest. The reason why this solution isn't optimal is that if I had multiple parameterized tests, I would have to repeat the loop for each one.

Comment: Maybe just change condition to the  ASSERT_LE(i, 0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change how the output of your tests is printed by deleting the default printer and adding your own. Read this [part](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#using-event-listeners) of google-test advance guide.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  // Gets hold of the event listener list.
  ::testing::TestEventListeners& listeners =
      ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
  // delete default printer
  delete listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());
  // add your own
  listeners.Append(new MinimalistPrinter);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

How one can define such `MinimalistPrinter`? It is done by subclassing `::testing::EmptyTestEventListener`.  Just override `OnTestPartResult` to collect failures, and override `OnTestEnd` to print one-line summary.

---

Or you might just try `--gtest_break_on_failure` option.

Comment: Great answer. I was wondering if it was also possible to edit the way the XML file is generated by GoogleTest?

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268584/generate-google-c-unit-test-xml-report and/or https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/30 and/or  this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googletestframework/HVGPe9leCns